# How to show a video in browser from a URL in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am creating a web application using flask. I am able to upload the video from my local system and can show the uploaded video in the browser as well. But the next thing I want to do is to upload a video from the URL and show that video in the browser. Below is what I have tried:

```
`<div class="container">
        <form>
          <label for="homepage">Add your URL:</label>
          <input type="url" id="url_input" name="url_input" value="" placeholder="Enter URL here"><br><br>
          
          <iframe id="video_here1" src="" style="display: none" width="420" height="345" ></iframe><br><br>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('url_input').onchange = function(){
            var video = document.getElementById('video_here1');
            video.style.display = 'block'
            video.src = document.getElementById('url_input').value;
        }
        </script>
    </div>`
```

I am not able to show the video from the URL. Please see the attached screenshot for your reference.
[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help me to figure out how to upload and show a video from the URL in Flask? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have a direct link to the video file (e.g. vimeo.com/video.mp4) or download it and use the local filepath.

Comment: @Julius No. Unfortunately, I am not looking this way.

Comment: You could try to embed the video. This doesn't work for every link though.
Vimeo: https://vimeo.com/blog/post/how-to-embed-your-gorgeous-videos-across-the-nets/
YouTube: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780